# Center alignment of text in input field for opera mini

Tags: html, css, input, opera-mini, center-align

Is it possible to centrally align the text in an input field in Opera Mini?

I tried this, which works fine in other browsers:

`<input type="text" style="text-align: center; width: 280px;"/>`,

but in Opera Mini the input fields text is still left-aligned.

Comment: Did you check if the browser is in Single Column view? That overrides many of the page styles for readability, so that may be causing the centering not to work.

Comment: Single Column view is not activated. Activating it removes even more of the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a few attempts but it seems that unfortunately it's not possible.

I think the `input` control in that browser is quite simple and doesn't allow aligning, changing font size or some more complex properties like `border-radius`.

Tested with Opera Mini 7.1 in a Nokia C3.

Comment: Yeah, that is my conclusion as well.
`border-radius`, I think, is explicitly mentioned as not supported, but font and alignment is supported for other controls, but not `input` and `select` as far as I can tell (might be others, but those were the two I needed this time).